# DPY-3010 when connecting python-oracledb to Oracle DB 11.2 / Airflow

Tags: python, docker, airflow, python-oracledb

Oracle db does not support thin mode because it is an old version. How do I switch to thick mode in dockerfile?

This is my docker file:

````bash
FROM apache/airflow:2.5.0
RUN pip install cx_oracle
RUN pip install airflow-code-editor
RUN pip install black
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir apache-airflow-providers-oracle
USER root
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install libaio-dev -y \
    libaio1 \
    libaio-dev \
    build-essential \
    unzip \
    curl
RUN mkdir -p opt/oracle
COPY instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.9.0.0.0dbru.zip /tmp
COPY instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.9.0.0.0dbru.zip /tmp
RUN unzip /tmp/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.9.0.0.0dbru.zip -d /opt/oracle
RUN unzip /tmp/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.9.0.0.0dbru.zip -d /opt/oracle
RUN mv /opt/oracle/instantclient_21_9 /opt/oracle/instantclient
RUN ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so.11.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so || echo "yuppi"
RUN ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient/libocci.so.11.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient/libocci.so || echo "yuppi"
RUN rm -rf /tmp/instantclient*
USER airflow
ENV ORACLE_HOME="/opt/oracle/instantclient"
ENV OCI_HOME="/opt/oracle/instantclient"
ENV OCI_LIB_DIR="/opt/oracle/instantclient"
ENV OCI_INCLUDE_DIR="/opt/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include"
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/oracle/instantclient:$ORACLE_HOME"
USER root
RUN echo '/opt/oracle/instantclient/' | tee -a /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle_instant_client.conf && ldconfig```
````

Answer (score 0):

Switching mode is done in the application by a call to [`init_oracle_client()`](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#enabling-python-oracledb-thick-mode), not by any external configuration.  In Airflow initiate this call by setting the `thick_mode` option as shown in the [Airflow Oracle Connection documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-oracle/stable/connections/oracle.html).  This is done in the `extras` field:

```
{
   "thick_mode": true
}
```

Your Dockerfile is problematic and can be simplified:

- install `oracledb` not the old `cx_oracle` Python driver
- to connect to Oracle Database 11.2 you should use Oracle Instant Client 19 or lower
- you don't need to install the Instant Client SDK for python-oracledb (or cx_Oracle)
- you should not set ORACLE_HOME when using Instant Client
- I don't think you need OCI_HOME, OCI_LIB_DIR, or OCI_INCLUDE_DIR.  They are not used by python-oracledb, and are not referenced in Airflow that I know of
- you don't need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH since you are running `ldconfig`
- you shouldn't need to create the symbolic links because they already exist

Some references:

- [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/part-1-docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python).
- https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleInstantClient